# Angular 4 Keycloak

Tags: angular, keycloak

I'm implementing the Keycloak authentication service in my Angular 4 project. I use a service for logging in, logging out etc.

keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "my-front",
  "auth-server-url": "http://127.0.0.1:8180/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "app-frontend",
  "public-client": true
}
```

My keycloak.service.ts

```
export class KeycloakService {

    static auth : any = {};

    static init() : Promise<any>{
        let keycloakAuth : any = new Keycloak('../assets/data/keycloak.json');
        KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required'})
                .success(() => {
                    alert();
                    KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
                    KeycloakService.auth.authz = keycloakAuth;                    
                    KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.createLogoutUrl();                    
                    resolve(null);
                })
                .error(() => {
                     reject(null);
                });
        });
    }
    getToken() : Promise<string> {
        alert();
        return new Promise<string> ((resolve, reject) => {
            if(KeycloakService.auth.authz.token) {
                KeycloakService.auth.authz.updateToken(5)
                .success(function() {
                    resolve(<string> KeycloakService.auth.authz.token);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    reject('Failed to refresh token');
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

So, when I tried to access in my url http://localhost:4200, I get the login page of keycloak, but when I tried to connect I get a reload page like :
`http://localhost:4200/#state=c93e5c1f-0cb1-404f-81b6-202eef7add4d&code=VziF6tlMnl_iZaNWoJBWtiz0j6TIKAcb5_KCu29Nygo.5fb5511b-624c-4423-8232-bdcce3137bf4`

How can I show my home page ?

Comment: So which adapter are you using for authentication? Client, server? Also do you have any trace of your browser requests?

Comment: Hi, No I haven't trace, but I resolved it by adding web-origins in keycloak .. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3866

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: Yes I resolved it by adding web-origins in keycloak, It is a good issue ? I see this post and I report it , http://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3866